# Why echo$?' returns 0 even though 1 is expected?

Tags: c, exit-status

For the following program, I get 0 for echo$? even though I expect 1.

```
int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke the program and test its return status from your shell?

Comment: Buried in an answer comment is the important information that the questioner had not actually run the compiled program.

Answer (score 1):

Your program works just as you expect it to:

```
$ cat prog.c
int main()
{
    return 1;
}
$ cc prog.c
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
1
```

Note that if you do anything in-between running your program and outputting `$?`, the value of `$?` will be overwritten by the exit-status of the commands that you use.  For example,

```
$ ./a.out
$ echo "I ran the program"
I ran the program
$ echo $?
0
```

The `0` here is the exit status of `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

if I compile your code using gnu g++ on my system: echo $? gives me 1. Do you have the same problem with a code in c, bash, python, ...? Also: be aware that $? is available only for the last command's return: the $? for echo $? is 0.

Comment: I compiled the same code with 'gcc'. Still get the same result.

Comment: what distribution are you using? what terminal? (bash?). $? is a shell built in variable.

Comment: Also: are you: 1) compiling, obviously getting no error, 2)running the compiled binary, 3)running echo $? in that order, doing nothing in between, in particular between steps 2 and 3?

Comment: Oh, you caught my mistake; silly mistake. I wasn't running the compiled binary and expected '1' for the compilation. Thanks a lot for your guide.